# Passing an array to the magic get method

Tags: php, arrays, getter, magic-methods

Out of curiosity, is there a way of passing an array in the magic get method. It has to be only the magic get method, or something equivalent. (But it shouldn't be using another function to go that)

For instance, **IS THIS POSSIBLE?**

```
<?php
// Book.php
Class Book{
    /**
     * Hold the book's details
     * @var array
     */
    private $book_details = [];

    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $book_list[$name] = $value;
    }

    function __get($name)
    {
        if (is_array($name)) {
            $collect_info = [];
            foreach ($this->book_details as $item => $value) {
                if ($item == $name) {
                    $collect_info[$item] = $value;
                }
            }

            return $collect_info;
        } else {
            return $this->book_details[$name];
        }
    }
}
```

and in another file like **resourses.php**

```
<?php
// resources.php

    require_once "Book.php";

    $book = new Book();

    $book->name = "Somebook's Name";
    $book->author = "This awesome dude";
    $book->pages = "723";
    $book->about = "Programming Content";

    $book->name; // prints Somebook's Name

    print_r($book->(["name", "pages"]));

    // prints
    //   Array(
    //        [name] => Somebook's Name,
    //        [pages] => 723
    //   )
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. Create a __normal__ method which will be __understandable__ by others without `magic`.

Comment: So, it only works with a method huh?, Ok... What what do you think about it.. do you think it'll be a good addition?

Comment: __What__ will be a good addition?

Comment: The array form of the magic get function.